# how can i rotate element and change it's angle using html5

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change car angle by pressing left and right keys, the code below change the angle only one time, i need to change the angle every time i press on the left or right key. any help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#myCar {
    width: 60px;
    height: 30px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<img id="myCar" src="driver.png">
  <h1>myCar</h1>

<script>
function myFunctionR() {
    // Code for Chrome, Safari, Opera
    document.getElementById("myCar").style.WebkitTransform = "rotate(20deg)"; 
    // Code for IE9
    document.getElementById("myCar").style.msTransform = "rotate(20deg)"; 
    document.getElementById("myCar").style.transform = "rotate(20deg)"; 
}
function myFunctionL() {
    // Code for Chrome, Safari, Opera
    document.getElementById("myCar").style.WebkitTransform = "rotate(-20deg)"; 
    // Code for IE9
    document.getElementById("myCar").style.msTransform = "rotate(-20deg)"; 
    document.getElementById("myCar").style.transform = "rotate(-20deg)"; 
}


    document.onkeydown = checkKey;  
    function checkKey(e){
      e = e || window.event;
      switch(e.keyCode){
        case 37: myFunctionL(); break;
        case 39: myFunctionR(); break;
      }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show your current markup and code.

Comment: Please read SO rules on asking questions before you ask such questions

Comment: I've editted the question plz take a look

Comment: You wanna be looking at **[CSS `transform:rotate()`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp)** and how to access that **[through JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_js_transform)**

Comment: @funkwurm thank  you so much, I've used this but there is still a problem with my code. it change the angle only one time. i need to make it change every time i click on the key. see the code above I've edited it

Comment: Nice specification: But we are not here to write your code for you as there is no way to present an invoice and accept payment.

Comment: I've written the code actually, but i need to edit something to it in order to make it as i want. see the code above :) thank u

Answer (score 0):

You wanna *add* or *substract* an amount to the amount that's already there. I would do something like this:

```
function getAngle(el) {
    // Get the transform-value from any of the possible style-elements
    var transform = el.style.transform || el.style.WebkitTransform || el.style.msTransform;
    // return the degrees currently there or 0 if there is non
    return parseInt(transform.substring(7, transform.indexOf('deg)'))) || 0;
}
function setAngle(el, deg) {
    el.style.transform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    el.style.msTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    el.style.WebkitTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
}

function changeAngle(el, deg) {
    setAngle(el, getAngle(el)+deg);
}

function myFunctionR() {
    changeAngle(document.getElementById('myCar'), 20);
}
function myFunctionL() {
    changeAngle(document.getElementById('myCar'), -20);
}
```

Untested and probably buggy (maybe the `||` is not the best way to make it work in all browsers) but this should get you on your way.